# Unable to instantiate service service.FetchAddressIntentService: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service

I am having error in my manifest file.

service.FetchAddressIntentService has no default constuctor
so i have created constructor in service class as follows.
now i am getting exception..

any suggestion?

```
08-12 21:27:36.568  20148-20148/com.sunil.location.mylocation E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sunil.location.mylocation, PID: 20148
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service service.FetchAddressIntentService: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2570)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2567)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 21:32:36.611  20148-20148/com.sunil.location.mylocation I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 20148 SIG: 9
```

FetchAddressIntentService

```
public class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "fetch-address-intent-service";


    private static final String TAG = FetchAddressIntentService.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * The receiver where results are forwarded from this service.
     */
    protected ResultReceiver mReceiver;

    /**
     * This constructor is required, and calls the super IntentService(String)
     * constructor with the name for a worker thread.
     */

    FetchAddressIntentService(){
        super(TAG);

    }

    public FetchAddressIntentService(String name) {
        //Give the class name to worker thread
        super(TAG);
    }


        ............


        }
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sunil.location.mylocation" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="service.FetchAddressIntentService"
            android:exported="false"/>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have not specified any access modifier in front of your default constructor so its package private (default).
Hence your default constructor is only visible inside package.
Make it public or protected whatever is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the exception text says everything - you do not have a public constructor without arguments. As I can see you only have package local (without modifiers) constructor of that type - you just have to make it public